# Convert AVFileType to UTType

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am trying to query the file types supported by AVFoundation on a device, and then pass those file types to a UIDocumentPickerViewController's supported content types. AVFoundation reports the types as a `AVFileType`, while the picker takes `UTType`. The `AVFileType` seems rather opaque to me, that is I can't figure out what this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avfiletype) means and how it reconciles with what is shown when I print them. Because [they print out](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avurlasset/1386800-audiovisualtypes) looking like enums with rawValues:

```
__C.AVFileType(_rawValue: dyn.ah62d46dzqm0gw23sqf40k4pts3y1g7pbru00g55ssvw067b4ge8046p0), __C.AVFileType(_rawValue: public.pls-playlist), __C.AVFileType(_rawValue: dyn.ah62d46dzqm0gw23sqf40k4pts3y1g7pbru00g55ssvw067b4gq80c7perf1w85puqzx1n6xq), __C.AVFileType(_rawValue: public.aifc-audio),
```

But the docs say that the `AVFileType` is just a struct with some static constants. What is this type anyway, why does it show rawValues, and is there any way to extract that info and use it as a file type for a picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply initialize a new UTType object with AVFileType rawValue:

---

```
let utType = UTType(AVFileType.ac3.rawValue)  // <UTType 0x600001b68360> public.ac3-audio
```

---

```
extension AVFileType {
    var utType: UTType { UTType(rawValue)! }
}
```

---

```
AVFileType.ac3.utType  // <UTType 0x600001b68360> public.ac3-audio
```

Comment: ah, thanks. What does the rawValue mean in this context, on a struct, not an enum?

Comment: It is not an enumeration but `AVFileType` conforms to [RawRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable)

Comment: Note that not all enumerations conforms to RawRepresentable. i.e:  `enum NotRawRepresentable {` `case a,b,c` `}`
`NotRawRepresentable.a.rawValue` // error